# ssh to nested server and collect some information

Tags: ssh, gpu

I recently encountered some difficulties, that I want to write a script to automatically log in to nested servers to collect some info on each of them:(specifically, use `nvidia-smi` to collect the `GPU usage info` on each machine)

the nested server structure is like:
`user@boss`(`user@machine1, user@machine2, user@machine3, ...`)
normally we have to use `ssh` to log into `user@boss`, then `ssh` to specific machine to do our work, but it is not convenient to monitor all machine GPU usage, I tried to write one script like:

```
sshpass -p "xxxx" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
for v in machine1 machine2
do
        sshpass -p "xxxx" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no v
        echo $v
        nvidia-smi
done
```

but it only log into the user@boss, I'm not familar with server stuffs, is user@boss the root node, then machine1, machine2, ... are child node? can someone help?(note I dont have root priviledge)

**ADD** the servers including user@boss and user@machine1, user@machine2, ... all dont have `sshpass` installed, only `ssh` surported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use password authentication.  Use public-key authentication only, and have good, strong passphrases for your ssh keys.

   See [Why is using an SSH key more secure than using passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/why-is-using-an-ssh-key-more-secure-than-using-password) and the Linked and Related posts for interesting discussions about keys vs passwords.
2. You can configure ssh to always connect to a remote host using a proxy host.

e.g. in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host machine1 machine2 machine3
    ProxyJump user@boss
```

then `ssh machine1` will **always** connect via `boss`.

From `man ssh_config`:

> **ProxyJump**
>
> Specifies one or more jump proxies as `[user@]host[:port]`.
>
> Multiple proxies may be separated by comma characters and will be 
>   visited sequentially.
>
> Setting this option will cause `ssh`(1) to connect to the target host by
>   first making a `ssh`(1) connection to the specified `ProxyJump` host and
>   then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate target from there.

Comment: Thank you, but seems password or key authentication is only for security consideration, my major problem is that I want to write a short bash script that can automatically log in to `machine1`, `machine2`, `machine3`... to collect some info there with some commands, can you suggest specific ways on this purpose?

Comment: I told you the two important things you need to do what you want (key auth and proxyjump).  With those, you don't need to do anything more complex than a for loop like `for host in machine1 machine2 machine3 ; do echo $host; ssh "$host" nvidia-smi ; done`.   BTW, if "boss" doesn't have `sshpass` installed this is probably the only way you can do it without using an `expect` script (or similar, such as perl's `Expect.pm` or python's `pexpect`) - "boss" can't run a program that's not installed.

Comment: Thank you, I know can use a for loop to log in to machines properly with `for machine in $(seq 10 30)
do
     echo mahcine$machine;ssh deep$machine;nvidia-smi
done` but after log in to machine, the program stoped there, `nvidia-smi` is not run there, after I exit the machine, it log in to next machine, but still `nvidia-smi` not executed.

Comment: that's a different problem requiring a separate question.  but things you need to consider include: is nvidia-smi installed on the remote machines?  Is it in $PATH? Does the user have permission to run it?  Do they have permission to access the GPU device?

Comment: Thank you, managed to do it, turns out `ssh deep$machine` and `nvidia-smi` have to be put on the same line

Comment: yes, i didn't even notice you'd put an extra `;` in your for loop.   if you don't give `ssh` a command to run on the remote host then it will just give you an interactive shell on that host.  more generally, a new line (without a trailing backslash or something else that allows a line to continue on to the next line) indicates the end of the current command - the next line is a completely new command.